# datatables ColReorder plugin don't support RTL?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, right-to-left

I am using ColReorder plugin for datatables plug-in for jQuery, when i switch the direction of datatable between ltr and rtl in case of ltr it works fine but when switch to rtl the ordering restricted to most right position.

Comment: Can you post an example of it not working (edit your question to include code)?

Comment: @amphetamachine look at this example try to comment the css line of direction to see the difference:  http://jsfiddle.net/aBUH7/13/

Comment: **Edit your question to include code**